# To match multiple conditions using regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need support for creating a regex filter on a specific line. The requirement is like.

Any line including “Country=IN”                           ALLOW

Any line including “Country=”not "IN"                     Reject

Any line not including “Country”                          ALLOW

The word "Country" may be at anywhere in the line or may not be in the whole line.

Plz can someone support.

Comment: So really you're just looking to match anything line that does not have the string "Country= not IN", correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking to match anything with the exception of lines containing "Country=not IN" (and assuming the extra quotes are a typo):

```
/^((?!Country=not IN).)*$/
```

Comment: i tried this one ^((?!country\=IN).)*$  which helps in matching country=IN but need another condition mutually OR to above to match the line that doesnt have "country" at all

Comment: I'm unclear what you're looking for then. From your question, it appears you want to match everything *except* the string `Country=not IN`. Could you provide additional sample lines and whether or not each should be matched?